# When will HDFS be unavailable?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Name node is the single point of failure for HDFS. Is this correct?

Then what about Jobtracker? If Jobtracker fails, is HDFS available?

Comment: "Name nodes are a single point of failure. But what happens if a Jobtracker fails? Will HDFS stay available?" What is vague about that?

Answer (score 1):

HDFS is completely independent of the Jobtracker. As long as at least the NN is up, HDFS is nominally usable, with overall degradation dependent on the number of Datanodes that are down.

Comment: Which of the following scenarios makes HDFS unavailable?  A. JobTracker failure B. NameNode failure c. Secondary NameNode failure

Answer (score 0):

As Ambar mentioned HDFS as in the file system does not depend on the JobTracker. The current released version of Hadoop does not support Namenode high availability out of the box but you can work around it (e.g. deploy the namenode using a traditional clustering solution of active/passive with shared storage). 
The next release (2.0/0.23) does fix the namenode availability issue.

You can read more about it in a blog post by Aaron Myers ["High Availability for the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS)"](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/high-availability-for-the-hadoop-distributed-file-system-hdfs/)

If the JobTracker is not available you cannot execute map/reduce jobs

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If JobTracker is not available we can't execute map/reduce.If Namenode is not available,HDFS is not available.Both are indipendent.Is that correct ?

Comment: if the namenode is not available you can't execute map/reduce on HDFS so for most purposes you can say that map/redeuce is also not available